# How to don't run a parallels job in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

i have a problem,Where I'm using spring batch in my application, and she's running my two jobs in parallel, just what I need is running my two jobs as sequential step, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the two jobs are related and should always be run one after another, create a job that orchestrates the other two.  The orchestration job would be a parent and each of the job's steps would launch the other two jobs.  You can see an example of using the Job step in the Spring Batch Samples here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/jobStepSample.xml

Comment: So, spring batch always run two or more jobs in parallels ?
I configured my class using bean annotation.
Exists any configuration to run sequencial job ?, because spring batch start two jobs in parallels.

Comment: No.  Actually, on the contrary, by default it will run one at a time since it's configured with a `SynchronousTaskExecutor`.  However, once you enable the ability to run more than one at a time, there is nothing to prevent more than one running at a time.  Is there a concern with the orchestration job approach?

Comment: yes, because my two jobs write in mysql, causing lock in table. so i wanted to run jobs sequential.

Comment: How does the orchestration job cause a lock in the table?  The jobs don't run in parallel using the orchestration job approach.

Comment: I will try to describe my situation here. i have two jobs, after start my application, is called job1 and job2, after this he start first step from job1 and first step from job2, where in writer this two steps write in mysql. after some time return error of job1 with a message like this: lock in table mysql.

Comment: Can you share your configuration?